# What is the best way to create a random hash/string?

Tags: php, session, hash, md5

What is the best way of generating a hash for the purpose of storing a session? I am looking for a lightweight, portable solution.

Comment: If you want secure random strings, use something like [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random). This is a random string, not a hash. If you want a hash, PHP has several algorithms included, but you didn’t specify what you want to calculate a hash from. How to integrate this into session management is a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use PHP's built-in hashing functions, [**`sha1`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) and [**`md5`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php). Choose one, not both.

One may think that using both, `sha1(md5($pass))` would be a solution. Using both does not make your password more secure, its causes redundant data and does not make much sense.

Take a look at [**PHP Security Consortium: Password Hashing**](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html) they give a good article with weaknesses and improving security with hashing.

Nonce stands for "**n**umbers used **once**". They are used on requests to prevent unauthorized access, they send a *secret* key and check the key each time your code is used.

You can check out more at [**PHP NONCE Library from FullThrottle Development**](http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library)

Comment: Thanks. Im going to look into it

Comment: SHA1 can be broken as well (at least theoretically).  See [Hash function security summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function_security_summary) for details.

I'd go with SHA256 or SHA512.

Comment: Very old thread, but SHA1 is now officially broken! http://www.theverge.com/2017/2/23/14712118/google-sha1-collision-broken-web-encryption-shattered

Answer (score 78):

```php
bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

1. [mcrypt_create_iv](https://www.php.net/mcrypt_create_iv) will give you a random sequence of bytes.
2. [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/bin2hex) will convert it to ASCII text

Example output:

```
d2c63a605ae27c13e43e26fe2c97a36c4556846dd3ef
```

Bare in mind that "best" is a relative term. You have a tradeoff to make between security, uniqueness and speed. The above example is good for 99% of the cases, though if you are dealing with a particularly sensitive data, you might want to read about the [difference between MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM and MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173803/mcrypt-dev-random-freezes-but-mcrypt-dev-urandom-works).

Finally, there is a [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib) "for generating random numbers and strings of various strengths".

Notice that so far I have assumed that you are looking to *generate a random string*, which is not the same as *deriving a hash* from a value. For the latter, refer to [password_hash](https://www.php.net/password_hash).

Comment: Just a little PSA: `mcrypt_create_iv` was deprecated in PHP 7.1.0. Use [`random_bytes`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) instead.

Comment: Removed in PHP 7.2.0: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 47):

[`random_bytes()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) is available as of PHP 7.0 (or use [this polyfill for 5.2 through 5.6](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)). It is cryptographically secure (compared to `rand()` which is **not**) and can be used in conjunction with `bin2hex()`, `base64_encode()`, or any other function that converts binary to a string that's safe for your use case.

## As a hexadecimal string

[`bin2hex()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) will result in a [hexadecimal](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string that's twice as many characters as the number of random bytes (each hex character represents 4 bits while there are 8 bits in a byte). It will only include characters from `abcdef0123456789` and the length will always be an increment of 2 (regex: `/^([a-f0-9]{2})*$/`).

```
$random_hex = bin2hex(random_bytes(18));
echo serialize($random_hex);
```

> s:36:"ee438d1d108bd818aa0d525602340e5d7036";

## As a base64 string

[`base64_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) will result in a string that's *about* 33% longer than the number of random bytes (each base64 character represents 6 bits while there are 8 bits in a byte). It's length will always be an increment of 4, with `=` used to pad the end of the string and characters from the following list used to encode the data (excluding whitespace that I added for readability):

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789
/+
```

To take full advantage of the space available, it's best to provide an increment of 3 to `random_bytes()`. The resulting string will match `/^([a-zA-Z\/+=]{4})*$/`, although `=` can only appear at the end as `=` or `==` and only when a number that is not an increment of 3 is provided to `random_bytes()`.

```
$random_base64 = base64_encode(random_bytes(18));
echo serialize($random_base64);
```

> s:24:"ttYDDiGPV5K0MXbcfeqAGniH";

Comment: Does this method have any advantages over creating a string that uses extra special characters. I use a method randomly generates same length but with larger character combination that have numbers, uppercase, lowercase and specials characters. Which mathematically looks more secure.

Comment: @Zortext `random_bytes()` is built into PHP (so could be faster than anything you create) and can be trusted to be cryptographically secure (compared to `rand()` which is **not**). As for `bin2hex()`, you could convert the binary to something else without too much concern of affecting security (it'll just be more time consuming, but could save a few bytes for the end user). The easiest would probably be `base64_encode()` which would only ~33% be larger than the binary input. Alternatively, you could use `random_int()` in a loop that maps to an array of characters.

Comment: @Zortext If your concern is security of the session, increase `16` to a number that makes you feel better. 16 bytes is 32 hex characters which means there are `16^32` different possibilities, or 3.4e38 possibilities. So I'd recommend figuring out what the attack surface you're trying to prevent looks like and adjust the number of bytes accordingly. If your concern is storage used by the cookie/session, use `base64_encode()`, or roll your own using `random_int()` and an array of more than 64 characters.

Comment: what is the `serialize` for?

Comment: @Merc The `serialize()` calls are not necessary and are only to illustrate that the output is a string and how many characters each string is in comparison to the number of random bytes generated. Both use 18 random bytes, but `bin2hex()` builds a 32-character string while `base64_encode()` makes a 24-character string. As far as what you should use: you only _need_ `bin2hex(random_bytes(18))` or `base64_encode(random_bytes(18))`; everything else is extra.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe uniqid() is what you need?

[uniqid — Generate a unique ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: Right now, I am using uniqid() but I read that using md5 on a uniqid() is not good.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) since php 5.3.0 to generate a pseudo random string of bytes. You can use this function and convert it in some way to string using one of these methods:

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$hash = base64_encode($bytes);
```

or

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$hash = bin2hex($bytes);
```

The first one will generate the shortest string, with numbers, lowercase, uppercase and some special characters (=, +, /). The second alternative will generate hexadecimal numbers (0-9, a-f)

Answer (score 5):

Use `random_bytes()` if it's available!

`$length = 32;`

```
if (function_exists("random_bytes")) {
    $bytes = random_bytes(ceil($length / 2));
    $token = substr(bin2hex($bytes), 0, $length)
}
```

[Check it on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use apache's [mod_unique_id](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_unique_id.html) to generate a random unique number to store my sessions. It's really easy to use (if you use apache).

For nonce take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce there's even a link to a PHP library.

Answer (score 0):

I generally dont manually manage session ids. Ive seen something along these lines recommended for mixing things up a bit before,  ive never used myself so i cant attest to it being any better or worse than the default (Note this is for use with autogen not with manual management).

```
//md5 "emulation" using sha1
ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
```

Comment: I dont use the built in php session functions as I do not have much control over them and maybe unsecure.

Comment: I can assure you, that they are more secure than any function you would think is secure :)

Answer (score -3):

Different people will have different `best` ways. But this is my way:

1. Download this `rand-hash.php` file :
   http://bit.ly/random-string-generator
2. `include()` it in the php script that you are working with. Then, simply call
   `cc_rand()` function. By default it will return a 6 characters long
   random string that may include `a-z, A-Z,` and `0-9`. You can pass
   `length` to specify how many characters `cc_rand()` should return.

Example:

1. `cc_rand()` will return something like: `4M8iro`
2. `cc_rand(15)` will return something similar to this: `S4cDK0L34hRIqAS`

Cheers!

Comment: This does not generate cryptographically secure values as it uses [`rand()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

Comment: But... if you're not using it for cryptographically secure values, this works well. I'm just trying to create an identifier for something in my program. +1.

Comment: link in article is broken, does not work anymore.