# Glide library show me a wrong picture

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a DB that stores the paths of the photo.
In my application I show this photo with Glide library.

The paths are:

```
http://www.mysite.example/username/0.jpg  
http://www.mysite.example/username/1.jpg
```

But I have a problem when I delete the row on the DB table, the path of the photo restarts from `0` and when I show the photos with Glide, it shows me the photo that was stored before.

How do I fix this problem? Clear cache?

This is a snippet of the code

```java
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView imageView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        }
        imageView = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        Glide.with(context).load(path.get(position).getPath()).into(imageView);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Check out their documentation on caching, maybe it will help you. - https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use hash name for your image name in server side. so the url nearly  never be same .

Comment: if you use php in server side use this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293684/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-random-hash-string

Comment: I generate hash but in database save inesistent character like this á‡z®ÎŠÀ

Comment: I use hash("sha512", $imageName, "FALSE"); where imageName is username+System.currentTimeMillis()